# Unable to assign delegate in global method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton

I have a singleton and in it I create a custom method that is going to be used by multiple viewcontrollers. The method is to display an email composer.

```
-(void)emailSend:(NSString*)bodyStr inVC:(UIViewController*)vc {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        NSString *messageBody =  bodyStr;
        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = vc; // <-- warning
        [mc setSubject:@"Say Hello"];
        [vc presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }else{

        // Not setup
    }

}
```

On other viewcontrollers I call this by:

```
[[MySingle singleton] emailSend:@"Testing" inVc:self];
```

The warning message is assigning to

> id __Nullable from incompatible
>   type UIViewController *__strong

Any way how to make it work?

Comment: hi dear, can you try this :     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[[MySingle singleton] emailSend:@"Testing" inVc: weakSelf];           **OR**        Replace the self with classname (try with strong and weak)

Comment: You need to add the delegate to your VC

class MyVC: <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: change as : ** nVC:(id)vc**.

Comment: @KKRocks thanks it works. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes on your method :

**From :**

```
-(void)emailSend:(NSString*)bodyStr inVC:(UIViewController*)vc
```

**To :**

```
-(void)emailSend:(NSString*)bodyStr inVC:(id)vc
```